# How to try a true or false syntax in java

Tags: java

I have the fallowing code

```
while (b == true){
      System.out.print("input the account balance without tax: ");
      int inner = input.nextInt();
      List[x]=inner;
      x=x+1;
}
```

and I want to check if my user inputs a word it would do:

```
b =false
```

So I would exit this loop. In python we had try() and except.
I don't really know what to do in java.

Comment: Just put an if in the loop: `if <condition> b=false`.

Comment: You literally do exactly what you just described. Check if the input is a word and set `b` to false.

Comment: use `try{...}catch{thorow NAME_OF_YOUR_EXCEPTION_JAVA;}`

Comment: @hagubear No, that's terrible for something this simple.

Comment: @hagubear No, no, and no. Exceptions are for *exceptional* behavior and they are especially not to control logic flow.

Comment: You need to get an `String` from the `InputStreamReader`. Store this `String` in a variable. Then check whether the `String` is equal to your word using the `equals(String s)` method. If so, set `b` to `false`. Otherwise convert the `String` into an int using `Integer.parseInt(String s)` and store it in your array.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to change

```
while (b == true){
```

to use [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) like

```
while (input.hasNextInt()){
```

Comment: Hmm, while an interesting insight into what the OP might be doing, I don't think this will work well if the input stream is `System.in`  It never terminates so the loop will hang forever, waiting for more input.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do a while(true) statement, which isn't good programming practice, the final code snippet would look something like this,

```
boolean someCondition = true;
while(true){

    if(someCondition == false){

      break;

    }

 //and here you would put something that would make that check condition eventual 
 //false to break the loop

}
```

This is prone too error but would work for your purposes.

That being said, the answer Elliot gave is the correct one and worth considering.